# how to display numbers over 100 from a text file in python after sorting them?

Tags: python

I have a project that needs me to sort numbers however that was fine 
until the number 113 also i don't know how to sort over 100 can someone 
help me do that
it is for an exam

```
scoresdoc = open("scoresdoc.txt","r+")
lines2 = scoresdoc.read()
x = lines2.split()
x.sort(reverse=True)
print("\nTop Five Scores:\n")
print(x[0:5])
scoresdoc.close()
```

the code currently works fine however won't work with numbers over 
        100 which is a problem the expected was the top five scores however 
        the numbers over 100 wouldn't show up`

Comment: The _numbers_ in `x` are `str`s. If they are all `int`-like, try using `x=sorted(map(int, x))`

Comment: thanks Chris but the int then gives me the error message so do i int the number i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following implementation.

**Code:**

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as opened_file:
    lines = opened_file.readlines()
lines = list(map(int, lines))
lines.sort(reverse=True)
print("\nTop Five Scores:\n")
print(lines[0:5])
```

**test.txt:**

```
2
45
3
56
6
3
2
34
5
63
3
42
45
6
1
112
22222
2
34
4
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py

Top Five Scores:

[22222, 112, 63, 56, 45]
```

**EDIT:**

If you have elements which cannot be cast to integer, you can use the following implementation:

**Code:**

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as opened_file:
    lines = opened_file.readlines()
int_list = []
for elem in lines:
    try:
        int_list.append(int(elem))
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong value: {}".format(elem))
    except Exception as unexp_exc:
        print("Unexcepted error: {}".format(unexp_exc))
        raise unexp_exc
int_list.sort(reverse=True)
print("\nTop Five Scores:\n")
print(int_list[0:5])
```

**test.txt:**

```
2
45
3
asdf
56
6
3
dsfa
189
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
Wrong value: asdf

Wrong value: dsfa


Top Five Scores:

[189, 56, 45, 6, 3]
```

Comment: You are welcome! It this is the answer for your question, please mark your question as answered.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\yr 10\computer science\NEA project\project.py", line 129, in <module>
    lines = list(map(int, lines))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n' this was the error i got

Comment: It means you have some elements in your text file which are not castable to integer. You can debug the wrong elem whit this code: `with open("test.txt", "r") as opened_file:
    lines = opened_file.readlines()
int_list = []
for elem in lines:
    try:
        int_list.append(int(elem))
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong value: {}".format(elem))`

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can see a more robust implementation which is able to filter the elements which cannot be cast to integer.